# In Odoo, how do I override _file_write in the ir_attachment class?

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

In the Odoo 9 source code the class ir_attachment has the following comment:

> The 'data' function field (_data_get,data_set) is implemented using
>       _file_read, _file_write and _file_delete which can be overridden to
>       implement other storage engines, such methods should check for other
>       location pseudo uri (example: hdfs://hadoppserver)

It tells me I can over ride the read, write and delete methods, but I have not been able to find any documentation on how to do so.

I tried overriding like I would other Odoo modules by creating an module with this code:

```
class Attachments(osv.osv):
    _inherit = 'ir.attachment'

    def _file_read(self, cr, uid, fname, bin_size=False):
        r = super(Attachments, self)._file_read(cr, uid, fname, bin_size)
        return r

    def _file_write(self, cr, uid, value, checksum):
        name = super(Attachments, self)._filewrite(self, cr, uid, value, checksum):
        return fname
```

However, I set several breakpoints and it appears Odoo is not registering these function overrides. Is there a different way to override methods in runtime directory?

Comment: Have you tried using `_inherit = 'ir.attachment'` instead of `_name = ....`?

Comment: @travisw: Doh! Good catch on my mistake. I've updated the code and my text to focus on my original question.

Comment: Is your file getting imported correctly? Such as your `__init__` files are calling your `Attachments` class into Odoo. If so, perhaps you can try adding a field to the `ir.attachment` model and see if it is successfully added to the database model. If that works, you might try mirroring the `ir.attachment` methods from Odoo's 10.0 code. It uses `models.Model` (instead of `osv.osv`) and `@api.model` which might be easier to use to inherit.

Comment: @travisw: I was missing importing the model in __init__.py. I had it originally, but while trying to debug the previous error I'd moved things around. Odoo is now accessing my override code. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

See this github project for a complete and working example: https://github.com/tvanesse/odoo-s3